# Autoprocess in PHP

Tags: php, process

I'm doing with PHP. I have a form. Each time users submit that form, I want to save these data to database first (to save time for users) then deal with these data later. But I don't know how to deal with these data automatically. Any code can auto process in server to treat these data automatically everytime having new record in database?
Did you get my question? Any suggestions? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: No, I didn't get your question. What do you want to do with the data "later"?

Comment: I didn't get to, you should get your question first before posting it

Comment: Are you asking how to store information in a database from an HTML form? Or are you asking how to run a script every time a new record is stored in the database which will automatically process the newly stored data?

Comment: Cron Job ??? Message Queue ?  This are what you should look at

Comment: The submit form is a link and I get the content of website that link point to. But this process is time wasting. So I want to process later to save time for users. Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 'Stored Routines' that get triggered when the data changes, see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

or, slightly less elegant, use a cronjob that launches every set amount of time and have a "processed" flag on the database that allows the script to know what records it has already processed and which ones it hasn't and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. 'Stored Routines' has only SQL statements but I want it auto process like a crawler. Any more suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what, "like a crawler" means exactly, but, If I understand correctly, the other option is to have a crontask that calls a php script that looks for any rows it hasn't processed, processes it and sets a flag to "1" for example. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for trigger http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html